# Error Occured while coping the code into already existing project

Tags: java, android, parsing

After all the effort and with the help of stackoverflow community people i'm able to parse my website content and fetched the website content into listview of android app, it works charm, i had created this project seperately so, now included the codes in my original project, but now when i click the respective page it gets crash, dont know the reason...

//Here's the logcat:

```
 11-28 15:58:22.927: W/KeyCharacterMap(938): No keyboard for id 0
11-28 15:58:22.927: W/KeyCharacterMap(938): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
11-28 15:58:26.188: D/AndroidRuntime(938): Shutting down VM
11-28 15:58:26.188: W/dalvikvm(938): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rebuix.com/com.rebuix.com.Home}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:245)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at com.rebuix.com.Home.onCreate(Home.java:46)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-28 15:58:26.207: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: did your Home.java extends ListActivity ? if in your xml listview change the id to android:id="@android:id/list".